# Parameters in TCL using ns2

Tags: linux, bash, tcl, ns2

how can i sent this values

```
24.215729
24.815729
25.055134
27.123499
27.159186
28.843474
28.877798
28.877798
```

to tcl input argument?
as you know we cant use pipe command because tcl dosent accept in that way!
what can i do to store this numbers in tcl file(the count of this numbers in variable and can be 0 to N and in this example its 7)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is pretty easy to do in bash, dump the list of values into a file and then run:

```
tclsh myscript.tcl $(< datafilename)
```

And then the values are accessible in the script with the argument variables:

```
 puts $argc;  # This is a count of all values
 puts $argv;  # This is a list containing all the arguments
```

Answer (score 1):

You can read data piped to `stdin` with commands like

```
set data [gets stdin]
```

or from temporary files, if you prefer.  For example, the following program's first part (an example from [wiki.tcl.tk](http://wiki.tcl.tk/367)) reads some data from a file, and the other part then reads data from `stdin`.  To test it, put the code into a file (eg `reading.tcl`), make it executable, create a small file `somefile`, and execute via eg

```
./reading.tcl < somefile


#!/usr/bin/tclsh
#  Slurp up a data file
set fsize [file size "somefile"]
set fp [open "somefile" r]
set data [read $fp $fsize]
close $fp
puts "Here is file contents:"
puts $data

puts "\nHere is from stdin:"
set momo [read stdin $fsize]
puts $momo
```

Comment: just to be clear, `gets` reads one line and removes the trailing newline (so the variable name `data` is a bit misleading), and `read` reads a bunch of characters (including newlines).

Comment: @glenn, right, for purposes of the demo I didn't mention those points.  Also note, the `[read stdin $fsize]` will read at most $fsize characters from stdin (ie reads fewer if EOF occurs before that many) and $fsize could well be irrelevant to whatever appears on stdin.

Comment: If you're going to read everything, just `read $channel`; Tcl's got good buffer management.

Answer (score 1):

A technique I use when coding is to put data in my scripts as a literal:

```
set values {
    24.215729
    24.815729
    25.055134
    27.123499
    27.159186
    28.843474
    28.877798
    28.877798
}
```

Now I can just feed them into a command one at a time with `foreach`, or send them as a single argument:

```
# One argument
TheCommand $values
```

```
# Iterating
foreach v $values {
    TheCommand $v
}
```

Once you've got your code working with a literal, switching it to pull the data from a file is pretty simple. You just replace the literal with code to read a file:

```
set f [open "the/data.txt"]
set values [read $f]
close $f
```

You can also pull the data from stdin:

```
set values [read stdin]
```

If there's a lot of values (more than, say, 10–20MB) then you might be better off processing the data one line at a time. Here's how to do that with reading from stdin…

```
while {[gets stdin v] >= 0} {
    TheCommand $v
}
```